# Age of Mathoverlow

Tags: bug, status-completed

As was pointed out [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/i-found-mo-has-been-included-in-se-network-today#comment37030_10067), Mathoverflow is listed as being 2012 years old [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest).

Comment: It is true, MathOverflow was actually a secret society in the days of the Roman empire. When Nero was watching Rome burning it was actually a fire started by the MO guys, because someone had suggested that $\pi$ is irrational! :-)

Comment: Coming to think about it, this could be a cool RTS game in the line of Age of Empires.

Comment: @AsafKaragila whereas the first thing that came to mind for me was Age of Aquarius...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StackExchange.com consumes our [public API](http://api.stackexchange.com/), which is guaranteed to return a launch date for every site, but didn't for MO. Sites that were not launched through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) need to have this value explicitly set, which hadn't happened for MO yet. It's set now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By tomorrow, all those "zero denominator" problems will go away.  Right?