# On StackExchange.com MO is still Uncategorized

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange

Obviously MO is listed at All Sites/All, but instead of also being at All Sites/Science, like M.SE, it's in All Sites/Uncategorized.

(I noticed it back when [the age was wrong](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/78/8181), but it hasn't been fixed yet, so I decided to mention it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed. MathOverflow now shows up under [Science](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science).

Comment: Math should totally go under Life/Arts.